# How do I list all admin users in couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

As an admin, I can list all couchdb users easily:

```
http://localhost:5984/_users/_all_docs
```

I can use _session to see if the user I am currently logged in as has admin privileges:

```
http://localhost:5984/_session
```

(just check that roles includes _admin)

But how can I get a list of all users in the system with admin privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a CouchDB admin, you basically create entry in the *admins* section of the configuration.

You can get the list of administrators at this url:

- http://localhost:5984/_config/admins

For 2.3.1:

- http://localhost:5984/_node/couchdb@127.0.0.1/_config

Comment: I get {"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."} or that URL (when logged in as an admin) This is for couchdb 2.3.1

Comment: You gave me the idea to check the config section in fauxton. It does show the admins. So then I watched the http requests that fauxton makes: http://localhost:5984/_node/couchdb@127.0.0.1/_config